# Android built-in security for apps?

Tags: android

Whenever you go to Google's Play Store and install an app, a list of all the necessary access is shown and a confirmation to proceed with the installation is required.

Let's imagine I would like to install Angry Birds:

> - In-app purchases
> - Identity
> - Photos/Media/Files
> - Wifi connection information
> - Device ID & call information

How exactly does Play Store come with this list?

- Does their algorithm actually analyze the code to come up with that list?
- Is the vendor responsible to list those needed access?
- A different way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The security model for Android is that all of the protected resources (Identity, Contacts, Camera, GPS, etc, [[Full list of permissions you can request here]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)) are protected inside the operating system API. That means that an app does not have direct access to the hardware, instead it has to ask the operating system to talk to the hardware for it. That way, the operating system has a chance to check the app's permissions and refuse to give the data.

**An Example:**

Let's say I write an app that wants access to the GPS location, I have to do two things:

1. At install time, request the appropriate permissions in the manifest file `manifest.xml`:

   `<manifest ... >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ...
   </manifest>`
2. At runtime, ask the operating system to give me the GPS location:

   `String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);`

During that call to `.getLastKnownLocation(...)` the operating system will check that my app has the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. If it does, then it'll hand me back the location data, if not then it'll throw a [`java.lang.SecurityException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SecurityException.html) and refuse to give me any data.

Comment: To be fair, Windows apps also ask the OS to talk to hardware for them too (it's the whole point of an OS).  Windows even has mechanisms to enforce security restrictions (ACLs).  It's just that historically, those restrictions were set to "wide open".  The major difference from a technical standpoint is that on Windows, an app inherits *all* of the user's access rights, whereas on Android security is handled on a per-app basis.

Comment: @josh3736 Fair, I'll remove that.

Comment: @josh3736 because a linux user is created for every app installed. It also makes outstanding isolation between apps which is not available on desktop OSes.

Answer (score 18):

Every permission needs to be declared in the AndriodManifest.xml before an app can use them. For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

to be able to receive SMS.

This manifest will also be used to list the permissions shown when you download the app in the store.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any kind of double check from Google's side to ensure those apps are really only doing what are they supposed to?

Comment: You can't run the app if you use something that need permissions and isn't declared in the manifest. Which gives the nice [SecurityException](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+SecurityException)

Comment: @BadSkillz Keep in mind, in Android M and forward, you should be able to annotate code that can request permissions from the user to enable more features in the application at runtime. See https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: @BadSkillz a SecurityException isn't necessarily fatal, the app could `catch` it and continue running.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth that's true, but the functionality that caused the security exception still wouldn't execute, so it still wouldn't breach the given permissions.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Right. "Can I use the camera? No? Ok...". I'm just pointing out that `You can't run the app if you use something that need permissions and isn't declared in the manifest.` isn't exactly true.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth ah, i see. is it even possible to grant permissions to an app that aren't in its manifest, though?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Umm, sortof, in CyanogenMod (and I think Android M) you can toggle permissions off through the settings menu after an app is installed, so even if the permission is in the manifest, it might not be on at runtime. And according the comment above, in Android M you can ask for extra permissions at runtime, to which the user can say "Yes" or "No". Crashing if they say "No" would be bad design.